# Custom view scrollbars

Tags: android, android-view, android-scrollbar

I have a custom view and I managed to enable scrollbars on it using this post: [Android: Enable Scrollbars on Canvas-Based View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869276/android-enable-scrollbars-on-canvas-based-view).
The problem is that I can't scroll them, even though I overrode the compute functions.
Here is the code that creates the view:

```
final PaintBoardView paintBoardView=new PaintBoardView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        0,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,(float)0.8);
paintBoardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
ViewGroup boardToolsContainer=(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.board_tools_container);
boardToolsContainer.addView(paintBoardView);
```

And here's the view's constructor:

```
super(context);
setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
TypedArray styledAttributes=context.obtainStyledAttributes(
    R.styleable.View);
initializeScrollbars(styledAttributes);
styledAttributes.recycle();
```

And:

```
@Override public int computeHorizontalScrollRange() { return 2000; }
@Override public int computeVerticalScrollRange() { return 2000; }
```

As I said, I see the scroll bars, but the scrolling is not working.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I'm just using the view's scrollBy and scrollTo methods to do the scrolling myself in the onTouchEvent function.