# How to show scrollbars on a TextView programmatically

Tags: android, scroll, textview, scrollview

I have searched and searched to find an answer to how to add a vertical (or horizontal) scrollbar to a TextView without having to use the XML just to add the line: android:scrollbars="vertical".

There has to be a way to do this programmatically that doesn't require sticking this within another ScrollView.

I've just found out how and because I am way to excited about this and want to help anyone else who is stuck with the same question, here it is:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rusian Yanchyshyn, posted the key in his answer at [Android: Enable Scrollbars on Canvas-Based View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869276/android-enable-scrollbars-on-canvas-based-view/8582996)

With the help of an anonmous class & an initializer block we can now do the following:

```
            TextView textViewWithScrollBars = new TextView(context)
            {
                {
                    setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                    setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
                    setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);

                    // Force scrollbars to be displayed.
                    TypedArray a = this.getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[0]);
                    initializeScrollbars(a);
                    a.recycle();                        
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work with API level 21 and above as the initalizeScrollbars method has been removed..

Comment: for existing TextView?

Answer (score 2):

```
// try this
activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("demotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotext");
        textView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        textView.setLines(3);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        addContentView(textView,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

Comment: Hi Haresh, the whole point of this is that "setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true)" doesn't show the scrollbars on it's own.

Comment: you have to also set this property setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

Comment: @HareshChhelana Cool, How can we enable automatic scroll to the last line? User usually want to see updated message but not old one always.

Answer (score 0):

first - Make a style.xml

```
<style name="VerticalScrollableTextView">
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarFadeDuration">0</item>
</style>
```

second - use ContextWrapper

```
val textView = TextView(
        ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.VerticalScrollableTextView)
    )
    textView.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

That's All!

Answer (score -1):

**Show only when scroll**

Xml (in textView element):

```
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

**OnCreate:**

```
textView.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
```

Comment: Did you read the question?  The question is how to do this *without* using xml.

Comment: yeah, but all these xml elements have analog in programaticly!