# Remove initializeScrollBars() from Custom view in Android API level 21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have one custom class having initializeScrollBars() in its constructor.

In API 21, the method was removed, so i am not able to build the app on Lollipop 5.0.I have searched and found that, there is no alternative provided by android officially.

(https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes/android.view.View.html).

I have checked this link: [initializeScrollbars is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448771/initializescrollbars-is-undefined) and noticed that one developer suggest us to remove the method and let it on the View class by defining R.styleable.View_scrollbars attr which is not internal.

I just don't get it.

Google have answered for this issue as:

"The API has been removed because R.styleable is not public or stable. There is no safe way to pass a TypedArray into that method. Don't call the method."(Ref: https://github.com/GDG-Korea/PinterestLikeAdapterView/issues/31)

- Can anyone light me a path how to remove the method
  initializeScrollbars() from the custom view?
- Can i simply remove initializeScrollbars() from constructor ?
- What is the best way to initialize scrollbars of a custom view.?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Struggling with scrollbars on a custom view in API 21.

Comment: I also need the solution. Please provide me if you are done this.

Comment: Unfortunately no alternative solution found yet. I removed it from my code.