# Cannot resolve method 'initializeScrollBars(android.content.res.TypedArray)

Tags: java, android, scrollbars

I am trying to build this project from the UltimateAndroidCamera from [here](https://github.com/rexstjohn/UltimateAndroidCameraGuide)

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TwoWayView, defStyle, 0);
        initializeScrollbars(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the lib is not updated regularly and is facing the same issue as this - [initializeScrollbars is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448771/initializescrollbars-is-undefined)