# Is there really no clean way to programmatically add scrollbars to a custom view?

Tags: android, android-scroll

I want to add scrollbars to my custom view programmatically. Before Lollipop, this was done in the constructor like so:

```
setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.View);
initializeScrollbars(a);
a.recycle();
```

([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6199356/1197719))

Now with the introduction of Lollipop, Google made the `initializeScrollbars()` API private so it's no longer available [(see here)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77745)

So people have [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036532/1197719) to just manually import `initializeScrollbars()` and call it, like so:

```
final TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[0]);
try {
    // initializeScrollbars(TypedArray)
    Method initializeScrollbars = android.view.View.class.getDeclaredMethod("initializeScrollbars", TypedArray.class);
    initializeScrollbars.invoke(this, a);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
a.recycle();
```

This does the trick but of course it's a hack.

So does this mean that more than 4 years after the introduction of Lollipop and the removal of `initializeScrollbars()` it is still impossible to programmatically add scrollbars to a custom view and that the only safe way to do that is to inflate an XML or is there a clean solution to do this in the meanwhile?

It's hard to imagine for Google to remove `initializeScrollbars()` without providing an alternative way to do what it does... especially since it has been 4 years now and adding scrollbars to a custom view looks like a rather common task so I'm really puzzled why this is apparently so complicated to achieve programmatically.

Comment: `It's hard to imagine for Google to remove initializeScrollbars() without providing an alternative way to do what it does..` — you obviously don't know Google.

Comment: No, I don't :D But seriously, it's such a common task and the only way to do it is to inflate XML? I'm still reluctant to believe this.

Comment: `initializeScrollbars()` has had protected access since at least JellyBean. You should have no trouble calling it from your View subclass. You just can't call it from other classes.

Comment: Oh sorry I see. It has the removed tag, meaning the SDK won't show it. However, there is a reason for why it's been removed: `It's not safe to use this method from apps. The parameter 'a' must have been obtained using the View filter array which is not available to the SDK. As such, internal framework usage now uses initializeScrollbarsInternal and we grab a default TypedArray with the right filter instead here.`

Comment: Yeah, there is a reason, but there is no replacement AFAICS. That's what my post is about.... they just nuked it without providing a replacement :(

Comment: I can show you many other examples of Google removing features without replacements. It's something you need to get used to. You also should be using `initializeScrollbarsInternal` in your reflection, since `initializeScrollbars` doesn't have any function.

Comment: Why? I've just checked the Android source code and `initializeScrollbars` seems to call `initializeScrollbarsInternal`, doesn't it?

Comment: It does, but with the default View TypedArray. It ignores the one you pass.

Comment: Is that of any significance? I just want to have some scrollbars, I don't care what they look like ;)

Comment: Actually, I don't think you really need to call `initializeScrollbars()`. Have you tried without it?

Comment: Yes, I've just tried it and it doesn't work. When leaving out the call to `initializeScrollbars()` no scroll bars show up. It is necessary. At least on Android 7, which is my test system, that is.

Comment: Then I guess you'll need to stick with reflection.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that ;)

Comment: does the `ScrollView` created programmatically show the scrollbars? if so, did they use `initializeScrollbars()` method in `ScrollView.java`?

Comment: No, they don't use `initializeScrollbars()` at all in `ScrollView.java`. They also don't use `setHorizontalScrollbarEnabled()` and `setVerticalScrollbarEnabled()`.