# Android Studio doesn't recognize JAVA 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have added JAVA 11 to android studio to Build Tools -> Gradle like below:

[image]

app/build.gradle:

[image]

SDK:

[image]

Still when checking source it still shows JAVA 8:

[image]

and also when app runs, the features on Java 11 which don't exist on Java 8 cause the app to fail with missing exception.

java -version shows:

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You also have to check your project settings (not just general IntelliJ settings), make sure your project is configured for Java 11. File / Project Structure (shortcut: `⌘ ;`)

Comment: It shouldn't? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/54129834/2612030.

Comment: check your java version in command prompt :  java --version

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan 
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.

Comment: mac m1 monterey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247600/discussion-between-kim-m-and-anandh-krishnan).

Comment: Did you try using the Embedded JDK?

Comment: Yes I did, JAVA 8 still persists

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add java version in app level build.gradle file.

```
   compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

[image: like the image bellow]

Comment: JAVA 8 still persists!

Comment: can you share your compileSDk version?  from pp level build.gradle file

Comment: here it is:

buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31

Answer (score 0):

Try first to invalidate cache and watch carefully with XMLs Android studio need a proper cross checking but strangely its configuration process is not properly align.

If unable to do this restore /Reset Android Studio then Add/Enable JAVA.