# How to determine Java Version per Android OS version

Tags: java, android, code-analysis, runtime-environment

I was looking (hoping) for a simple mapping from each android OS version to a version of Java.

More specifically. I am focusing on the Android OS side (not the application side), the ART: what version of the JVM does it uses.

I still have some hope due to source code diving seems to relate it to the java supported by dx (I guess now d8 and r8), the dex compiler.

In libcore/libart/src/main/java/java/lang/AndroidHardcodedSystemProperties.java:

```
final static String[][] STATIC_PROPERTIES = {
// None of these four are meaningful on Android, but these keys are guaranteed
// to be present for System.getProperty. For java.class.version, we use the maximum
// class file version that dx currently supports.
{ "java.class.version", "50.0" },
{ "java.version", JAVA_VERSION },
```

But the android developer blog may rather imply the library of java used is *ad hoc*/*custom*
([blogpost](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/java-8-language-features-support-update.html)) with a mix of versions:
First openjdk 1.7 with *desugared* features of openjdk 1.8
Now more like 8 ([but not all features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)) with *desugared* features of Java 8+.

Comment: "the ART: what version of the JVM does it uses" -- it does not use any version of the JVM. ART is its own runtime. "a simple mapping from each android OS version to a version of Java" -- what do you mean by "a version of Java"?

Comment: Fair point. Better question could be, at its core(hence I mentioned ART), what version of Java is each version of Android shipped with ?

Comment: Again: what do you mean by "version of Java"? Please be very specific about what you mean here. A VM is not the same as a bytecode format, neither of which are the same as a class library, etc.

Comment: Ok. I try to know what version of the java runtime classes (e.g. java.lang.String) is used and compiled. From which jdk are they taken from (6,7,8,9,11, a mix) depending on the OS version. (thx for helping me being more precise btw)

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76621845/6396174)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.

To whomever might be interested, I analysed the openjdk java classes in each release version of libcore, from Android 7 to 13.
I compared to which version of openJDK each class is closer to (post android dev team modifications).

The results are published in this article (repository link in the article):
https://www.abartel.net/static/p/secdev2023-AndroidJCL.pdf